# How to transfrom dataset in the wanted form

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame I created like this
I wanted to convert it into a data frame where there are two columns genre and person associated with it. Something like this:
Desired form:

So I looped over and checked the condition but it was very brute-force so I wanted to do it without using loops

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not post images or external links, have a look at [How to ask a good
question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking sample of the data provided.

```
df = DataFrame({
    'Anime':['Shingeki', 'Fullmental'],
    'Genre':[['Action','Drama','Fantasy','Military'],
            ['Action','Military','Adventure','Comedy']]
})
df
```

**Input df**

```
    Anime       Genre
0   Shingeki    [Action, Drama, Fantasy, Military]
1   Fullmental  [Action, Military, Adventure, Comedy]
```

**Code**

```
df = df.explode('Genre').groupby('Genre', as_index=False).agg(list)
df
```

**Output**

```
    Genre        Anime
0   Action      [Shingeki, Fullmental]
1   Adventure   [Fullmental]
2   Comedy      [Fullmental]
3   Drama       [Shingeki]
4   Fantasy     [Shingeki]
5   Military    [Shingeki, Fullmental]
```

**Explanation**
We are first applying `explode` on `Genre` column to unlist all elements of `Genre` column and then grouping the resultant df on `Genre` and applying `list` function of `Anime`.